# :PlugUpdate is required every time I open vim

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-vimtex, plugin-vim-plug

I’m setting up my LaTeX environment for vim, but the snippets (Ultisnips + vim-snippets + Gilles Castel’s tex.snippets with some changes) only work after I run `:PlugUpdate` (using vim-plug). I have to run this every time, and I don’t know why. There are no error messages.

I don’t want to write a script to run `:PlugUpdate` automatically because it only works with a connection. Do any of you know how to fix this?

Comment: So snippets don't load? Or is ultisnips itself not working?

Comment: @Zoe The snippet completion doesn’t work until I update the plugins

Comment: Can you share more about your environment, such as the contents of your vimrc perhaps? Also the `:scriptnames` command can be useful to display which scripts Vim has already sourced... Please [edit] your question to add more details.

Comment: @filbranden Nevermind, I changed something in my vimrc, and it works now. I have no idea why, but i’m not complaining. Thank you!